# How to get latest 50 transactions for a BCH address?

Tags: transactions, api, bitcoin-cash

Is there an API from where I can get latest received transactions for a bitcoin-cash address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blockexplorers typically provide APIs that serve exactly that sort of data. For example the [address call](https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/blob/master/API_DOCUMENTATION_EN.md#link_bitcoinaddress) of the Blockchair API
 returns the latest 100 transactions the address was involved in.

You would retrieve the data for example by calling

```
curl https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/dashboards/address/<someAddress>
```

where you'll need to replace the address at the end of the url with your own. If you want to see what you'll get, you can hit the above url with an [example address](https://api.blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/dashboards/address/qpwr5uu9wxq7f9mrkt2z4z8t8pcf9w9wwg0s05jzvg) in your browser:

[image]

Comment: I have a full node running in my system. I'm not sure which method to use to get the transactions for an address not generated within my node. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, I didn't get at all that you meant to look it up from your own node. Next time be sure to include a bit more background on what you're trying to do. However, to answer that, Bitcoin Core and software forked from it does not maintain a full address index, it only indexes addresses that are its own. If you want a full address index, you have to either create it yourself or use another software. Also see, e.g. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/77685/5406

Answer (score 1):

you can search to find it. there are a lot of API,s which help you.
as an example try https://explorer.bitcoin.com/bch.